# How can I register a filter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My module is created like this with Typescript:

```
angular.module('admin', ['ngMessages'])
    .service('homeService', HomeService)
    .controller('adminHomeController', AdminHomeController)
    .controller('adminContentController', AdminContentController)
    .filter('sdate', function ($filter) {
        var angularDateFilter = $filter('date');
        return function (theDate) {
            return angularDateFilter(theDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        }
    });
```

On my HTML page I reference a filter like this:

```
{{ row.createdDate | sdate }}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n <- sdateFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.8/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n%20%3C-<div data-ui-view="content" id="contentBlock" class="ng-scope">dateFilter
    at http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:80:20
    at http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:3837:27
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:3969:53)
    at http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:3842:53
    at getService (http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:3969:53)
    at Object.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:4001:25)
    at http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:3843:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:3969:53)
    at null.$filter (http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:14624:34)
    at Parser.filter (http://127.0.0.1:17316/Scripts/bundle/library.js:10627:27)
```

I then tried doing this:

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [
        'access',
        'admin',
        'authentication',
        'ngMessages',
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .controller('appController', AppController)
    .filter('sdate', function ($filter) {
        var angularDateFilter = $filter('date');
        return function (theDate) {
            return angularDateFilter(theDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        }
    })
```

Still I get the same error. Is there something wrong with the way I am registering the filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you see something like this

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n <- sdateFilter
```

It often means a function parameter that represents a dependency was compressed to a single letter by some kind of JavaScript compiler (closure, uglify, etc.. etc..)

`sdateFilter` resolved correctly. Angular is indicating that `sdateFilter` depends upon `n` with `n <- sdateFilter`. The next part `nProvider <- n` means Angular tried find a provider called `n`.

So what dependency does `sdateFilter` have? Well you are trying to inject `$filter` so that's the only dependency, and something has renamed it to the letter `n`.

You can fix this by using array notification to define the dependencies. This will list the dependencies as a string in the order of the function parameters. Angular will use this even if the parameter names don't match.

```
angular.module('admin', ['ngMessages'])
    .service('homeService', HomeService)
    .controller('adminHomeController', AdminHomeController)
    .controller('adminContentController', AdminContentController)
    .filter('sdate', ['$filter',function ($filter) {
        var angularDateFilter = $filter('date');
        return function (theDate) {
            return angularDateFilter(theDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        }
    }]);
```

Once you start using array notation you can call your parameters anything.

Example;

```
    .filter('sdate', ['$filter',function (n) {
        var angularDateFilter = n('date');
        return function (theDate) {
            return angularDateFilter(theDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        }
    }]);
```

See also: [Angular Injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm 99% sure you are correct with this very clear answer. I will test out your suggestions and expect to accept the answer.

Comment: @SamanthaJ I've spent a lot of time trying to fix these errors. It gets a lot harder when everything in the error is just a single letter, and the call stack is purely angular. So make array injection a strong habit. It'll save you a lot of time later.

Comment: Alternatively, incorporate an [automated tool](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to do this for you as part of your build process